# How to clear data in listbox

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

Ok, I thought this will be simple, but apparently I still didn't find the solution.

So I want to clear my listbox with the click of a button.

I used `lstDatabase.RowSource = vbNullString` but it wipes whole data, together with my headers.

How to clear the data in listbox, but to leave headers?

Comment: Please also mention how are you populating the listbox. That will give some hint for the solution

Comment: it's filled with RowSource

Comment: You can only get the headers from the row above your RowSource - no RowSource = No headers

Comment: In furtherance of  the question from @NareshBhople; Where is the source data for your `ListBox`. *Where* is the `RowSource` object? Is it a range on your worksheet or something else? Please edit your question to include enough information for us to understand *how* the data is added and *where* from.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine two ranges using union method. If your entire data is in Range("A1:E10") on Sheet named "Sheet1", where Range("A1:E1") are headers and Range("A2:E10") are records; then you can define two ranges - one headers and one for records. Combine them with Union method. Use the Combined Range in populating the lstDatabase Listbox. And when you want to clear the listbox, set the rowsource = headers range.

```
Dim header as Range, records as Range, allData as Range
Set header = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E1")
Set records = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:E10")
'Combine header and records into allData
Set allData = Union(header, records)
'Populating the listbox like
lstDatabase.RowSource = allData
'Clear the listbox like, keeping header only.
lstDatabase.RowSource = header
```

Comment: Allow me a hint: the `RowSource` property needs a **string** value (not a range object) to be assigned to; see my *late* answer post to this elder question leaving column heads despite empty data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Function Listbox_ClearAllItems(listbox As Object)
    Dim lb As listbox
    Set lb = listbox

    If lb.ListCount <> 0 Then
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To lb.ListCount - 1
            lb.RemoveItem (0)
        Next i
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: OP commented *"it's filled with RowSource"*, i.e. the listbox is bound to the indicated range; so you won't succeed in removing the list's items individually.

Answer (score 0):

**Show headers despite empty data in RowSource-bound ListBox**

> The `ColumnHeads` property cannot exist without a `RowSource` bound to the listbox; if you delete the `RowSource` specification, there are no more `ColumnHeads`.

Take into account also Tim William's comment

> *You can only get the headers from the row above your RowSource
> `- no RowSource = No headers`*

So you need a tricky work around meeting both ends.

Assuming you have **initialized** your listbox already via something like

```
With lstDatabase
    'activate headers for RowSource bound listbox
    .ColumnHeads = True                         ' << allow headers !     
    
    'further example settings
    .ColumnCount = 5
    .ColumnWidths = "50;50;50;50;50"
End With
```

/: you might leave the wanted headers

- by referencing empty data based on
  an **extra (hidden) worksheet** (e.g. Sheet2) *containing nothing than the `row 1:1`* **captions** with follwing *empty* row(s) and
- by disabling actions in the virtually empty row source.

Note that you need

- to reference the 2nd (=empty) range row to include the captions above
- to disable the listbox in order to prevent from scrolling via `.Enabled = False`
- to assign a string value to the RowSource property  via a range address property (not a range object!)

**a) How to display the cleared data maintaining headers**
[image: ListBox headers]

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim hidden As Range
    Set hidden = Sheet2.Range("A1:E1").offset(1)    ' refer to empty after header row 1:1
    'Clear the listbox like, keeping headers only.
    With Me.lstDatabase                     ' reference ListBox
        .Enabled = False                    ' << Disable ListBox
        .RowSource = hidden.Address(External:=True) ' display empty data
        ''alternatively:
        '.RowSource = hidden.Parent.Name & "!" & hidden.Address(0, 0)
    End With
End Sub
```

**b) How to display the original data**

If you want to regain the original records (e.g. in Sheet1) you just have

- to restore the  the original data reference for
  a complete display and
- to re-enable the listbox via

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim records As Range
    Set records = Sheet1.Range("A2:E10")  ' heads are taken from the row above data
    'Populating the listbox like
    With Me.lstDatabase             ' reference ListBox
      .Enabled = True               ' << Re-Enable listbox
      .RowSource = records.Address(External:=True)
      ''alternatively:
      '.RowSource = records.Parent.Name & "!" & records.Address(0, 0)
    
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @TomislavBoberic Posted a late reply to your question how to leave headers in an empty rowsource-bound listbox as imo there was no fully valid answer yet. - Feel free to accept/upvote if you find my approach helpful.